# Getting "no pg_hba.conf entry for host" when configuring pg_hba with host name

Tags: postgresql, authentication, database-connection

I configured pg_hba.conf using a hostname (instead of IP address) verifying correct host access (this is documented at [Postgres Documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html)):

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
host    all         all         hostname.domain        password
```

At first time it works, but after a day or so (probably when our DHCP-Server assign a new IP address for hostname) it won't work and I get the error:

```
FATAL: no pg_hab.conf entry for host "192.168....", user ....
```

I am using postgres 9.3.5 on ubuntu 14.04.

Why does host based authentification not working with host names? Is there any additional setting?

Thank you,
Franz

---

as commentors said, in server log are more detailed error messages and asking our DNS responsible, he said, that there might be some mis-configuration; thus it's probably not the fault of PostgreSQL

Comment: If there's a local name resolution cache on the server (which is certainly recommended for performance), that goes in the way of ever-changing IP addresses.

Comment: Log in the server log to see if there is more info.  The client message is intentionally terse to avoid leaking info to an attacker.  Also, is your reverse DNS working reliably?